# Java paste bug in some programs

Tags: java, netbeans, copy-paste

I'm a Newbie in Java programming. I have wrote this program to paste "Hello world!" every second. The program run properly and the text pastes in many windows programs such as Notepad, Microsoft Word, Browsers and every program's textarea or inputbox. But in some programs my code didn't work for example Windows End Task Manager or Garena room.

Now my question is: Can some programs denies JAVA codes for security reasons? If it's true how to enable Java in them?

Be aware that I use NetBeans IDE for programing and compiling the jar file. My code is as below:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.snippets.desktop;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class SimulateMouseMoveAndKeyPress {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    try {

        // Create counter 

        int counter = 0; 

        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            String myString = "[" + counter + "] Hello world!";
            StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection (myString);
            Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getSystemClipboard ();
            clpbrd.setContents (stringSelection, null);
            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            counter = (counter)+1; 
        }

    } catch (AWTException e) {

        System.out.println("Low level input control is not allowed " + e.getMessage());
    }

  }

}
```

Please help me. Thanks all.

Comment: Don't leave us in suspense; tell us if your code received an `AWTException` or not.

Comment: Regardless of the question, should you reverse the order of: `r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);` so that `CONTROL` is released after the `V`?

Comment: `c# sendKeys()` also not work for taskManager .

Comment: why? is this for security reason?

Comment: i don't know .may be.

Comment: > Regardless of the question, should you reverse the order of: r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V); so that CONTROL is released after the V? Unfortunately your solution not works.

Answer (score 0):

`Can some programs denies JAVA codes for security reasons?` The no-Java programs are not aware of any Java program. They simple react to the Ctrl-V hot key (coming thru the operating system) and paste what they find in the systems clipboard in their structure. Or not, that should be the case where you won't see your "Hello world" string.

Probably where you don't see your pasted data, they won't react to a manual Ctrl-V either.

---

The [Robot docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) says:

> Using the class to generate input events differs from posting events
>   to the AWT event queue or AWT components in that the events are
>   generated in the platform's native input queue. For example,
>   Robot.mouseMove will actually move the mouse cursor instead of just
>   generating mouse move events.

Your generated events goes into the system event queue or not (should throw an Exception). Seems they work for some, others not. But AFAIK that is **not due to use Java** to create the events.

Comment: Oh thanks PeterMmm. As I know you say: > They simple react to the Ctrl-V hot key This means that the program restricts Ctrl+V. NO that's not true. The Ctrl+V works when I manually press them and the text properly pastes in the input-fields of these programs.
And what means: > The no-Java programs are not aware of any Java program Is this means my program (witch I try to paste text in its input-field) didn't read JAVA codes?? If it is what must I do? convert the program to other language like C#? Dose C# copy and paste codes works on any windows programs?
Thanks.